# Enum.ToString return wrong value?

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

I have a simple enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("Zero")]
    Zero,
    [Description("A positive number")]
    Positive,
    [Description("Any integer")]
    AnyInteger,
    [Description("A negative number")]
    Negative,
    [Description("Reserved number")]
    Reserved =2
}
```

However, running the the following code:

```
MyEnum temp = MyEnum.AnyInteger;

string en = temp.ToString();
```

sets the en string to Reserved.

Why does it happens?

Is there is some other way to set the string to the used enum string (in this case AnyInteger)?

Comment: `MyEnum.AnyInteger==MyEnum.Reserved`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when defining an enum the first value start with `0` and it going up from there unless you define other wise, so in your case it's:

```
public enum MyEnum
        {
            [Description("Zero")]
            Zero, //0
            [Description("A positive number")]
            Positive, //1
            [Description("Any integer")]
            AnyInteger, //2
            [Description("A negative number")]
            Negative, //3
            [Description("Reserved number")]
            Reserved = 2 // it's 2 again
           }
```

you can define the same value twice (or more) in a enum. the `ToString` find a name with the same value:

```
MyEnum temp=MyEnum.AnyInteger; //temp = 2

string en=temp.ToString(); // return the name of the first name with value 2.
```

if you insist that "Reserved"  should have the value 2, put him in the right place of order. otherwise remove the `=2`

Comment: one more thing to keep in mind. in your code `(MyEnum.AnyInteger == MyEnum.Reserved)` is true...

Answer (score 4):

It happens because you have set reserved to 2.  If you want to set values for your enums, you should do all or none.

Comment: that's totally not true. you can have some values sets. and sometimes you need that. A - you can set the first value to X and all other values will automatically be X+1, X+2 ... B - In case most values are irrelevant to you but still you wish to have one value specific. like the reserved here but with a value that wouldn't normally be retched like 9999 or whatever.

Comment: Notice how I didn't say you have to set all or none, I said you should.  It was a recommendation, not a mandate.  I agree with you that you can do exactly what the sara did in her post, but then you can get bitten with a small bug like this one.

Comment: right... although I still don't think this is something you should avoid. just use with caution.