# How does C# decide which enum value as a returned one? Any rules?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I found a very intersting thing——Let's say:

```
 enum Myenum { a, b, c= 0 }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Myenum ma = Myenum.a;
            Console.WriteLine(ma);
        }
    }
```

The result is **a**, why?

And if I say:

```
 enum Myenum { a, b=0, c}
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Myenum ma = Myenum.a;
            Console.WriteLine(ma);
        }
    }
```

**The result becomes "b", why?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043027/non-unique-enum-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268250/enum-tostring-return-wrong-value

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why would you find duplicates and then post an answer anyway?

Comment: @Rawling: because i thought that they were just related(at least the first link is not a duplicate). I also found the documentation which was not mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter In that case, why did you propose it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [`Enum.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you
>   attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration
>   member's name based on its underlying value, **your code should not make
>   any assumptions about which name the method will return**. For example,
>   the following enumeration defines two members, Shade.Gray and
>   Shade.Grey, that have the same underlying value.

Related: [enum.ToString return wrong value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268250/enum-tostring-return-wrong-value)

So i would assign unique values if you wannt to rely on the name:

```
enum Myenum { hello = 1, world = 2, qiang = 3 }
```

Comment: @ths: yes, but you have to know that `Console.WriteLine(ma)` uses `Enum.ToString` and you have to know that this is documented there which is unfortunately often not the case. If it was so simple i wonder why the related (or even duplicate) questions' answers didn't mention MSDN.